# Coin Change Leetcode

Tags: arrays, dynamic-programming

Problem: https://leetcode.com/problems/coin-change/

Solution:
https://repl.it/@Stylebender/HatefulAliceblueTransversal#index.js

```
var coinChange = function(coins, amount) {

    let dp = Array(amount + 1).fill(Infinity); //Fill dp array with dummy values

    dp[0] = 0; 

    for (let i = 1; i <= amount; i++) { 
        for (let j = 0; j < coins.length; j++) { //Iterate through coin denominations
            if (coins[j] <= i) { //Is current coin denomination less than amount? 
                dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], 1 + dp[i - coins[j]]); 
                //dp array[current amount - coin denomination]
            }
  }
}

return dp[amount] === Infinity ? -1 : dp[amount]; 
};
```

I understand the general conceptual flow of the solution of building the dp array from button up but I was just wondering with respect to Line 10:

dp[i] = Math.min(dp[i], 1 + dp[i - coins[j]]);

Why is there a 1 + when you select the current j'th coin denomination for consideration?

Is it because since there is a valid coin denomination, we have unlocked a new method to make up the i'th amount?

Answer (score 0):

- Yes, that's right. We'd be approaching the target amount by that one increment.
- If for instance 0.5 would be somehow the min increment, then that would have become 0.5 + the rest.

```
const coinChange = function(coins, amount) {
    const inf = Math.pow(2, 31)
    const dp = []
    dp[0] = 0

    while (dp.length <= amount) {
        let curr = inf - 1
        for (let index = 0; index < coins.length; index++) {

            if (dp.length - coins[index] < 0) {
                continue
            }

            curr = Math.min(curr, 1 + dp[dp.length - coins[index]])
        }

        dp.push(curr)
    }

    return dp[amount] == inf - 1 ? -1 : dp[amount]
};
```

- Maybe it would be easier to grasp in Python:

```
class Solution:
    def coinChange(self, coins, amount):
        dp = [0] + [float('inf')] * amount
        for index in range(1, amount + 1):
            for coin in coins:
                if index - coin > -1:
                    dp[index] = min(dp[index], dp[index - coin] + 1)
        
        return -1 if dp[-1] == float('inf') else dp[-1]
```